# 2d circle line collision

Tags: javascript, 2d, collision

I am trying to find the new position of a circle after it collides with a line, best explained by looking at this [explanatory image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G2JcB.png)

I've got

- Point A: Position of the circle [center of blue circle, start of red
  line]
- Point B: New position of the circle [end of red line]
- Radius R: Radius of the circle
- Point LS: Start of the wall [black line]
- Point LE: End of the wall
  [black line]

I would like to calculate the new position of the circle after it collides with the line [Position of the orange circle].

Comment: Your drawing on Figure 3. seems inconsistent; the ball seems like it should roll upwards. Do you mean the ball should travel to the nearest end of the line if it collides with the line?

Comment: @Mooshua Figure 3. was supposed to show the ball getting nudged off its original path after a partial intersection with the line. I've adjusted the image for clarity.